# Screen bounds do not change with orientation

Tags: ios9.1

Starting with iOS 8 screen bounds suppose to depend on orientation. But when I print the values in iOS 9.1, changing the simulator orientation - they stay the same!

```
    let h = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
    let w = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width

    dbpr("orient: \(devOrient.rawValue) w: \(w), h: \(h)")

    //the above prints this:
    orient: 1 w: 320.0, h: 548.0
    orient: 3 w: 320.0, h: 548.0
    orient: 2 w: 320.0, h: 548.0
    orient: 4 w: 320.0, h: 548.0
```

Reinstall of Xcode did not help. Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the reason was I had the Device Orientation under Target/General set to Portrait only.